# How to store an ArrayList in Vala?

Tags: arraylist, vala, wnck

it sounds like a stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer on Google.
Also, I'm a newbie to Vala (I code mostly in js, HTML and CSS), so please be specific.

I'm trying to get all open windows with `Wnck.Screen.get_default ().get_window ();`
(which seems to be working), but I'm unable to store the returned ArrayList.

How can I do that?

PS: can I use `ArrayList.foreach()` on this ArrayList?

Comment: Why can't you just do `var windows = Wnck.Screen.get_default().get_windows();`?

Comment: And to iterate, you can probably just do `foreach(Window window in windows){...}`.

Comment: @Hassan doing `var windows = Wnck.Screen.get_default().get_windows();` returns the following:
`error: duplicating List instance, use unowned variable or explicitly invoke copy method`

Answer (score 1):

The method returns `GLib.List`, not `Gee.List`. Gee is the new collections library for Vala. Most existing GLib code does not use it. You are free to use either, but there isn't a direct way to convert a collection from one to the other; if you want to do that, you'll have to write a loop and copy all the items.